# "ContentType matching Query does not exist" - only on SQLite, not MySQL

Tags: mysql, django, sqlite, django-orm, django-testing

I'm experiencing a strange bug with the way Django Test framework operates.

When using SQLite Database Backend, all of the tests crash with the following error:

```
  File "[]/core/tests/test_admin.py", line 91, in setUpSomething
    content_type = ContentType.objects.get(app_label='core', model='SomeModel')
  File "[]/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 151, in get
    return self.get_queryset().get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "[]/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 310, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name)
DoesNotExist: ContentType matching query does not exist.
```

However, the same code executes well under MySQL backend.

Clearly Django should make these functions agnostic of the backend used?

Comment: This answer may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17614700/2011147

Comment: I've tested this approach, and it doesn't work.. might be some transaction peculiarities of Django TestCase?

Comment: Same issue here: code works on MySql, but doesn't work with SQLite test database. I assumed that some version of `syncdb` was being used to set-up the db and that should update all ContentTypes model instances, but apparently not. Will investigate further.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I have no idea if my solution will be helpful, but it solved my issue, so here goes.

In my application code, I was attempting to query `ContentType` instances in the following way:

```
email = ContentType.objects.get(app_label="users", model="EmailAddress")
```

This worked fine with our actual MySQL database, but failed in test under a SQLite test database. However, if I switched the model definition to lowercase, it worked in both places:

```
email = ContentType.objects.get(app_label="users", model="emailaddress")
```

My guess was that this may have to do with the [default collation in MySQL of case-insensitivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769901/why-is-mysqls-default-collation-latin1-swedish-ci), so the first query *should not have worked* if I were comparing case-sensitively.

Indeed, when I looked at my database, all the `model` labels in the `django_content_type` table were lowercase and SQLite cares (by default) about case, so my queries in my tests were legitimately failing.